# convert string to asterisks in adf

Tags: regex, oracle-adf

I have an   < af:outputText > that contains pelephone number,

for example: "050-1234567"
I try to format it to "***-***4567"

How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
  <af:outputText value="#{login.phoneToSend}">
  </af:outputText>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom JSF converter to achieve this.

For that, you need to create a conveter class, register it in faces-config.xml and then use it as the converter of af:outputText.
In converter class use regular expression with String replace() to replace appropriate digits of your phone number with *

http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR31/web.1013/b25947/web_val006.htm

http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.com/2015/03/dealing-with-converter.html